# Sharepoint 2010 sandboxed solution

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sandbox

I am using SharePoint 2010 and creating a simple web part using Visual Studio 2010. When I create a SharePoint project in visual studio 2010, I specify "Deploy as a sandboxed solution" option. When I run the project, in a page in the SharePoint site when adding a web part I can see the web part. But when I try to add the web part to the page, I received this error "The sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request.".

I have searched on Google for the error message. The resolution to this error is to start the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service" service in the Central Administration. However when I look at the Services on Server using central administration site, I am missing this service. I don't see this service I was able to run the sandboxed solutions before but it is not working any more. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: On the services on your SharePoint server, is the "SharePoint 2010 User Code Host" available and running?? Run Services.msc.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed thus by going to Central Administration > System Settings > Manager user solutions. Under Load Balancing, I selected "All Sandboxed code runs on the same machine as a request" option and it is all working now.

For some reason I am still missing this service - "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service". However I have always had "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" service listed under Services on central administration site. And I am using SharePoint Server Standard Edition so it may be that for Standard edition I have this service instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not running the User Code services is kinda obvious :)

But there could be other cases too. Here is a good post on that:
http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/error-sandboxed-too-busy-handle-request/

Actually there are three more ways to resolve such problem inlcuding registry, hosts file and config settings.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have seen references to the name "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service" on MSDN and screenshots of the Central Administration website listing the service name as "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service", the service is listed as "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" on the Central Administration website on my development and test servers.

As described in the TechNet article [Sandboxed solutions overview (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704543.aspx):

> The sandboxed solutions service has different names, depending on where you access the service. In the SharePoint Central Administration Web site, the service is called the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service. In the Services console on the server, the service is called SharePoint User Code Host service. To avoid confusion, this article refers to the service as the "sandboxed solutions service."

In addition, the TechNet article [Enable sandboxed solutions on the farm (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff535775.aspx) lists two methods for starting the service:

1. From the Services on Server page of the Central Administration website, click **Start** in the **Action** column of the **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service** row.
2. From PowerShell, execute the following command: `Start-Service -Name SPUserCodeV4`